# Why is this Immediately Invoked Function able to see the incerment from the last call?

Tags: javascript, iife

I am under the impression that each time a function is called it is a new instance of that function. How is it that this code can take n and increment it without n being set back to zero each time?

```
const f = (function()
{
    let n = 0; 
    return function()
    {
        return ++n; 
    }
}());

console.log(f()); // prints 1
console.log(f()); // prints 2
console.log(f()); // prints 3
```

Comment: The function has access to the variable `n` in the *closure* created when `f()` was called. The closure persists between calls to the function.

Comment: That defines a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures): _A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared._. You should give they a read...

Comment: The function assigned to f has a single statement in it: `return ++n;`. How would calling that function ever set n back to 0?

Answer (score 0):

The IIFE is executed just once, and the value is assigned to `f`. So there's just a single closure, and it has a single `n` that gets incremented each time you call the returned function.

The result you expect would occur if you wrote:

```js
const f = function() {
  let n = 0;
  return function() {
    return ++n;
  }
};

console.log(f()()); // prints 1
console.log(f()()); // prints 1
console.log(f()()); // prints 1
```

This doesn't use an IIFE, it's just an ordinary higher-order function. Every time you call `f` you get a new closure.